# Meaning of "by way of" in "youth does not have to work against you **by way of** experience."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24O6hoGjbLA&list=LL&index=19) is a link to the full video, and below is an excerpt from what the actor says:

> Your youth does not have to work against you **by way of** experience.
>
> Your youth can be a virtue **by way of** what you ethically and earnestly expect of the world.

And I'm having trouble understanding what these sentences mean, mainly because I can't figure out which of the three definitions of "by way of" below fits in this context.

1. so as to pass through or across; via.
   "we approached the Berlin Wall by way of Checkpoint Charlie"
2. constituting; as a form of.
   "“I can't help it,” shouted Tom by way of apology"
3. by means of.
   "noncompliance with the regulations is punishable by way of a fine"

I understand all three definitions and the usage of them in each example sentences, but somehow can't work out what it means in the actor's remark that I referenced.

Comment: Forget about Definition 1 - it's either 2 or 3. The first sentence is rather odd. I assume he means "Youth doesn't have to be a disadvantage because of your _lack of_ experience".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd definition is the one that applies here. In your first example:

> Your youth does not have to work against you by way of experience.

Is implying that young people do not have as much experience and that has a negative effect, but it also states that this does not have to happen. This means that "by way of" is showing **HOW** the person's youth can work against them, which is, through their lack of experience. Likewise, the second example:

> Your youth can be a virtue by way of what you ethically and earnestly expect of the world.

is showing **HOW** the person's youth can be a virtue.

For further understanding here is an alternative sentence that could be used instead so you can compare:

> Your youth does not have to be a negative attribute due to your lack of experience

> It can instead be a benefit due to your ethical and earnest expectations of the world.